# convert one column value as key and another column value as value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Sample JSON getting from my service

```
{
    "appID": 1,
    "appName": "app1",
    "screenID": 1,
    "screens": "Login",
    "textID": 1,
    "keyName": "TEXT_1",
    "text_EN": "USERNAME",
    "text_DE": null,
    "text_PE": null
},
{
    "appID": 1,
    "appName": "app1",
    "screenID": 1,
    "screens": "Login",
    "textID": 2,
    "keyName": "TEXT_2",
    "text_EN": "PASSWORD",
    "text_DE": null,
    "text_PE": null
},
{
    "appID": 1,
    "appName": "app1",
    "screenID": 1,
    "screens": "Login",
    "textID": 3,
    "keyName": "TEXT_3",
    "text_EN": "Fingerprint Login",
    "text_DE": null,
    "text_PE": null
}
```

And I want to write the in text file as

> "TEXT_1"="USERNAME";
>
> "TEXT_2"="PASSWORD";
>
> "TEXT_3"="Fingerprint Login";

Comment: So what is stopping you? What is your *specific* question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2591098/5221149)

Comment: Nope, no JPA API to be seen here, despite the tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below using org.json:

```
String json = ""; // Your jsonArray
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i< arr.length() ; i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
  result.put(jsonObj.getString("keyName"), jsonObj.getString("text_EN"));
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
{"TEXT_1":"USERNAME","TEXT_2":"PASSWORD","TEXT_3":"Fingerprint Login"}
```